# History of a particular topic in graph theory.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, math-history

I was going through the book Handbook of Product Graphs by Sandi Sir et. al. They have mentioned in detail about all the graph products. I am more curious about the history of these products. I mean who defined these products and in which year. From searching on the web, I got to know only about Tensor product of graphs. Can anyone help me by providing desired sites and info from where I can get these details? It will mean a lot to me. Thanks a lot for the help.

**PS: Does the following pic indicate that in this article the graph product was first introduced?**

[image]

Comment: Haray, F.: Graph Theory, 1969, cites your article. But your article cites Čulík, K: Zur Theorie der Graphen. Časopis pro pěstování matematiky 83 (1958) (2) 133-155. https://eudml.org/doc/19137 The term "product" occurs already in König, D.: Theorie der endlichen und unendlichen Graphen, 1936. See Google Books: König "Theory of Finite and Infinite Graphs", and search its text there for "product*".

Comment: You could search the collected works of Arthur Cayley for "product": see the corresponding links in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Cayley